# Can't track in Google Analytics data from GetResponse

Tags: google-analytics

Our email marketer is sending email from GetResponse with a tracking code generated from another tool,
but we can't see if the users are coming from the email source.

Is it possible, because it is with tracking code generated from other tool, GA to mark it as direct traffic and is there a way to know it is coming from the email campaign? Also, I am not sure it is tracking it at all, becouse I don't see much traffic in the landing page. The GA is fired, I checked!

The tracking code includes the main domain and it redirects to a specific page.
Example: tracking.ourdomain.com/aff_c?offer_id=46&aff_id=76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check in Landing Pages report (or All pages report), filtering by `aff_id`, if there are any sessions.

To track in correct mode the source you have to use UTMs parameters. You can build your URL with UTM parameters using this **[tool](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/)**. It allows you to easily add campaign parameters to URLs so you can track Custom Campaigns in Google Analytics. Then you can find those sessions in `source / medium` report.

Comment: The problem is that we generate a specific tracking code that contains our domain, and that code we need to track events in other tool.Do you think we can build UTM parameter with the already built different code and it will work? I am afraid it will effect in some kind of way the other tracking tools results.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the other tool is generating a tracking code with a new domain, that is not a  subdomain to the original.This causes to lose the utm and the traffic is going in the direct chanel. We are working on resolving it.